# Why does my MySQL connection fail every night?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

First of all, I'm terrible at reading logs. I took a look at /var/www/mywebsitedomain.com/logs/error.log and couldn't figure out what exactly is going on.

It goes like this: I go to sleep at night and the website is up and running and the server is hovering around 65% RAM usage, CPU is around 5-15% usage. Everything is PERFECT. I wake up in the morning and my server is still running, but my WordPress website spits out an "Error establishing a database connection" error. EVERY. SINGLE. MORNING.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Restarting the MySQL service solves the issue.

I am on PHP5.5, nginx, MySQL. Latest version of WordPress. Also using PHP's Zend Opcache. I can link to log files if requested.

Comment: Yes, a relevant snippet of logs would be helpful, otherwise we have nothing to go on. Turn up the log level too, if you think it is necessary. Finally, when Wordpress is unable to connect, are you also unable to connect from the console? You need to ensure that the database is really down, and that it's not a PHP problem.

Comment: @halfer here is the error.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/up76mku7bncsaiz/error.log 

What are logs would you need? Is there a specific PHP log and/or a specific mysql log? I could dig those up for you if they in fact exist.

Comment: That's the PHP error log, and that's full of errors that you should tackle, though I don't think they are the cause of this problem. Your MySQL logs are much more likely to be useful. Aside: I would say that when publishing logs here, you should excise any user IP addresses or other personal information (though I appreciate they may be yours in this case). Also, you should paste only relevant parts, and do so in your question rather than in file locker sites. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A mysql.ini file might be needed to further help you. This seems like it might have to do with either server process config (nginx or whatever your implementation uses) or (more likely) the way that your sql service it set up.
Some info that might be helpful:
http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-58864.html

Comment: poking around: http://serverfault.com/questions/545468/php-loosing-connection-to-mariadb-server-each-3-hours

Comment: Check the limits of your logging size and if there are any upper limits on error logging or error-connections. You might also want to look for max_number_connections being filled due to unclosed db connects